# Convert air to apk timestamp issue

Tags: android, air, code-signing

I'm trying to codesign and timestamp an airi file. unfortunatley, i am only able to create an air file from this. but i need an apk. using the adt -package sytnax doesn't allow me to use the -tsa (timestamp) option.

so now i have a well signed and timestamped air file. how do i get an apk file from this? i am able to convert it without a timestamp, but then agin google play tells me my apk file needs a certificate ( i have a valid one purchased at globalsign.com) that is valid until 2033.

So i am able to create an apk file without timestamp but codesigned ( not helpful) or an air file codesigned and timestamped (not helpful either), but NOT what i need - an apk file codesigned AND timestamped.

i've searched this site http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html but was not able to find something suitable for me.

For my understanding i would say this is waht needs to be done:

```
Create a native package from an AIR or AIRI file:

adt -package 
-target packageType 
NATIVE_SIGNING_OPTIONS 
output 
input_package
```

so what i do is

```
./adt -package -target apk  -storetype pkcs12 -keystore aircertificate.p12  -tsa http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll myappname.apk myappname.airi
```

and what it says is:

-tsa option not supported

it doesn't say that when i use adt -sign, but signing only allows me to create an air file.

trying to simple convert my signed and timestamp air file to an apk file WITHOUT codesigning options like this

```
./adt -package -target apk myappname.apk myappname.air
```

shows that:

Signing options required to package APK

help please!!!

best regards

wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this trick: [Create Certificate Valid till 2033](http://ranjitfx.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/create-certificate-valid-till-2033-air-android-apk-upload/). It might be a workaround.

Comment: This only provides a self signed certificate